# the application stopped unexpectedly when play sound

Tags: android

> I created new **Android** App as it display static information , i had created **html5** and i call html5 files to my webview one of my html files function is play **mp3** when click on button I did my interface between html and android but when I test the project at device i had this message **the application stopped unexpectedly** .
>   i had this project from tutorial this tutorial haven't extends Activity  but when i removed it extends Activity **error** occurred " The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (WebAppInterface, int) " .

```
public class WebAppInterface  extends Activity    {
Context mContext;
MediaPlayer mp;


WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}


@JavascriptInterface

public void playsound() {
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(WebAppInterface.this, R.raw.sound);

}
```

}

```
 <input type="button" value="play mp3" onClick="playmp3()" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function playmp3()
  {
      Android.playsound();
  }
 </script>
```

> 06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.ramadan.WebAppInterface.showToast(WebAppInterface.java:23)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:52)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1150)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)
>   06-23 15:46:20.250: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

Comment: Please post the logcat trace.

Comment: check the level of the volume of STREAM_MUSIC

Comment: i think for audio player you need to call prepare

Comment: what do y mean with call prepare?

Answer (score 0):

> the problem was here

```
<code>



public void playsound() {

  MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
  mp.start();

}
```

> as I replaced WebAppInterface.this with mContext  and it worked well